# Circular relationship in the student management

Tags: database, database-design, relational-database

I am working on the student, TA, teacher and class relationship.
Each class is associated with one Professor and one TA, but a TA can be a student too. So, I came up with the idea like that (Photo below), but im not sure it is right to create a circular relationship like that?

Thank you in advance.

[image: Database 1]

Comment: That would depend of how you want to model it. Right?

Comment: But with respect to your Class entity, a TA is not part of that class within the context of a Student, correct?  Why not create a separate TA entity?  You are force-fitting a student to also be a TA (IsTA) flag.  What if in the future, you need to add other attributes to a TA (office phone #, email) or something, that is not relevant to a Student?  Where do those attributes go?  Or create a Faculty entity that can be used by both TA and professor.  Just a thought.

Comment: Do you mean to merge TA with professor as a Faculty entity? If yes, how do we know who professor is and who TA is? Also, we have to create 2 lines from Faculty to Class as we have one TA and one Professor being assigned to a class.

Answer (score 0):

Iff one can never be both a student and TA for the same class, it should never fully construct a circular relationship. You can prevent such from happening by checking for that case before allowing the values to be set in the database.

Even if it were to happen, I do not believe that there would an issue. The problem with circular relationships is that a value ends up never being defined (aka `StudentID` being referenced as a foreign key from each table, but never defined). This isn't the case in your database layout.

Comment: It is unrealistic if one can be both a student and TA for the same class. However, thank you for answering me and pointing out other case that I have to prevent.

Answer (score 0):

Your layout is not circular; You have:

`Class-list -> Student`

and

`Class-list -> Class -> Student`

Your layout would only become circular if you included `Student -> Class-list`

I don't see that you have a problem.

Answer (score 0):

It looks ok to me, but you might want to think about whether all TAs are going to be students.

The lines between tables are relationships.  So you're not really creating a circular reference in this case.

In one path, you are saying that one class_list has one student, and one class has multiple class_lists.  In another path, you are saying that one class has one TA, who must be a student (probably with the "isTA" flag set)

There's nothing here preventing a student from being in the class and a TA, but this wouldn't be the end of the world either.  It very well might be that this situation could arise.

Comment: The question is, what would you consider to be better?  You could create a "person" table instead of a student/TA/Instructor table, just in case a instructor is also a student.  Would it be better?  I don't know.